# Tried to install Wine in Ubuntu 21.10 and got error

Tags: package-management, wine, 21.10

I'm trying to install Wine from [WineHQ](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.10/winehq-amd64/) repository in Ubuntu 21.10. Once I'm at the last step it gets stuck as shown below at:

```
processing triggers for libc-bin (2.34-0ubuntu3.2)...
```

[image]

Then it goes to the usual terminal start. Am I supposed to see a install verification or is that just it?

Comment: How did you install wine? Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1402235/edit) the question to copy-paste the full terminal output?

Comment: As stated by @ArchismanPanigrahi, please update your question. 
A descriptive question helps folks answer your query correctly avoiding any chances of misinterpretation and errors.

Comment: This is normal. What do you mean by "verification"?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command to verify that there are no current package management issues.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If the above command executes successfully without errors then your system's package management is OK, otherwise please edit your question or post a comment about the results of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.